# Sign of real part and imaginary part zeta function at 1/2-x+iy and 1/2+x+iy

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I want to know what the sign of the real part and imaginary part of $\zeta(1/2+x+iy)$ and $\zeta(1/2-x+iy)$ are ,are they the same? for example in this case they are the same

zeta(0.25+I 10)=0.74513-0.0507106 I

zeta(0.75+I 10)=0.66-0.0517 I

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\rho=1/2+iy$ be the first zero of $\zeta(s)$. Then $\zeta'(\rho)$ has nonzero real and imaginary parts, and
$$\zeta(\rho+h)\sim\zeta'(\rho)h\qquad\text{as}\qquad h\to 0.$$
That is, if $x>0$ is sufficiently small, then both the real parts and the imaginary parts of $\zeta(1/2\pm x+iy)$ have opposite signs.

Comment: it seems to me that the real and imaginary parts of $\zeta(1/2-x+iy)$ and $\zeta(1/2+x+iy)$ have the same sign.

Comment: a counterexample will suffice.

Comment: Well, I *proved* that sometimes both the real parts and the imaginary parts of $\zeta(1/2\pm x+iy)$ have opposite signs. For a concrete counterexample, consider $\zeta(0.1+14.1 i)\approx -0.358787 - 0.10908 i$ and $\zeta(0.9+14.1 i)\approx 0.271012 + 0.0147528 i$.

Comment: thanks for your answer